# How to configure ExecStart for Gunicorn without WSGI?

Tags: gunicorn, systemd, sanic, uvloop

Systemd and Gunicorn require a wsgi file of some sort as the last arg to `ExecStart`: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html?highlight=ExecStart#systemd

With Django, this was in the main module as `wsgi.py`:

```
ExecStart=/home/admin/django/bin/gunicorn --config /home/admin/src/gunicorn.py --bind unix:/tmp/api.sock myapp.wsgi
```

But this file obviously doesn't exist when using Sanic and uvloop (I believe the new protocol is called ASGI). I tried substituting it for `app.py` which unsurprisingly didn't work:

```
ExecStart=/home/admin/sanic/bin/gunicorn --config /home/admin/src/gunicorn.py --bind unix:/tmp/api.sock myapp.app
```

How should this parameter be configured when using Sanic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start sanic with systemd, why don't you used supervisrod: [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

Boot -> Systemd -> supervisord -> gunicorn -> sanic

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock                       ; path to your socket file

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisord/supervisord.log    ; supervisord log file
logfile_maxbytes=50MB                           ; maximum size of logfile before rotation
logfile_backups=10                              ; number of backed up logfiles
loglevel=error                                  ; info, debug, warn, trace
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid                ; pidfile location
nodaemon=false                                  ; run supervisord as a daemon
minfds=1024                                     ; number of startup file descriptors
minprocs=200                                    ; number of process descriptors
user=root                                       ; default user
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisord/               ; where child log files will live

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock         ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[program:ctrlapi]
directory=/home/ubuntu/api
command=/home/ubuntu/api/venv3/bin/gunicorn api:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker -w 2
stderr_logfile = log/api_stderr.log
stdout_logfile = log/api_stdout.log
```

Comment: Sorry forgot, on the systemd side you need to execute supervisord -c supervisord.conf which is the config file mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet deployed this myself with Systend and gunicorn. But, the [documentation](http://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/deploying.html#running-via-gunicorn) seems pretty good on this.

> In order to run Sanic application with Gunicorn, you need to use the special sanic.worker.GunicornWorker for Gunicorn worker-class argument:

```
gunicorn myapp:app --bind 0.0.0.0:1337 --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker
```

With this in mind, how about this:

```
ExecStart=/home/admin/sanic/bin/gunicorn --config /home/admin/src/gunicorn.py myapp:app --bind 0.0.0.0:1337 --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker
```

I think the big piece you are missing is the `GunicornWorker` worker class.