# Multi Workers Sanic App And pyformance Lib for Metrics Reporting

Tags: python-3.x, graphite-carbon, sanic

I am trying to add metrics to [sanic based](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic) application using [pyformance metrics library](https://github.com/omergertel/pyformance).

```
import random
import time

from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

from pyformance import MetricsRegistry
from pyformance.reporters.carbon_reporter import CarbonReporter

registry = MetricsRegistry()
__reporter__ = CarbonReporter(registry=registry,
                          reporting_interval=10,
                          prefix='sanic',
                          server='localhost',
                          port=2003)
__reporter__.start()
app = Sanic()

@app.route("/api/v1/foo", methods=["POST"])
   def foo(request):

      timer = registry.timer(".foo")
         with timer.time():
         time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
         return json({"status": True})

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, workers=1, access_log=False, 
     debug=False)
```

When running 1 worker everything looks fine, but when configuring more workers no metrics being sent to carbon.

Any help is appreciated and also different approaches sending metrics to graphite from multi-workers sanic application.

Answer (score 0):

So multiple workers would basically subprocess the workers, might be something with IPC back to main process.

Try running multiple workers according to this and see if the same behaviour persists? [How to configure ExecStart for Gunicorn without WSGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362448/how-to-configure-execstart-for-gunicorn-without-wsgi/50639184#50639184)

Here gunicorn manages the processes.